# Material design and jQuery, scroll not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, conflicting-libraries

I am unable to make use of the *.scroll* method of jQuery while including Google's Material design. I have used Material Design Lite to make navigation bar of site.

If I exclude/remove **material.min.js**, then scroll method on *window* works perfectly. My simple jQuery code is this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
  console.log("scrolled");
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wwjoxtvp/2/

And here is codepen:http://codepen.io/MustagheesButt/full/PqBYop/

How can I get jQuery working without removing material design? Maybe some conflict is occurring, but console is not showing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you should bind the scroll event to the `.mdl-layout__content` class since material design lite is making that element scrollable.

```
$('.mdl-layout__content').on('scroll', function () {
  console.log('scrolled');  
});
```

Comment: so the scroll event does not bubbles upto window or document?

Comment: No it does not - only the ```.mdl-layout__content``` can be scrolled - material design lite does something with the layout.

Comment: What if I want to apply this for only one page, but .mdl-layout__content gets included on all page.

Comment: @RahulSagore then just execute the script above only on that specific page.

Answer (score 1):

dark4p solved it, but a possible alternative is to use:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ console.log('scrolled'); }, true);
```

The `true` indicating to use capturing rather than bubbling handling so it will still fire. I'm not sure whether this could have any negative interactions with material, though.

Comment: thanks. this also works. i was only thinking of bubbling

Comment: How can we check if the bottom of page has been reached using this code?

Comment: @RahulSagore You should be able to calculate that using `.scrollTop` and `height`/`.innerHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

.mdl-layout__content have overflow-y:auto and you scroll on this div. If you want you can change this but i don't recommend this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.mdl-layout__content').scroll(function(){
console.log('scrolled');
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wwjoxtvp/34/