# Material design lite, Check if scroll reached to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll, material-design-lite

I am Using Material Design lite with Angular.js. Having the problem to get the event called when the event reach to bottom.
I have tried almost every solution but not working. 
 Like jQuery solution :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ==      
        $(document).height())        
    {
        alert("bottom!");
    }
});
```

Or Javascript one:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
    if (document.body.scrollHeight == 
        document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) {
        alert("Bottom!");
    }
});
```

Nothings working.
According to this question : [Material design and jQuery, scroll not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31538512/material-design-and-jquery-scroll-not-working)

Scroll event will fire on .mdl-layout__content class, but still unable to get the event for bottom reached or not.

And probably I dont want to bind the even on "mdl-layout__content" class, since this will be included on every page. 
I just want this for one particular page.

**EDITED:**
This code is working fine but has problem:

```
function getDocHeight() {
     var D = document;
     return Math.max(
            document.getElementById("porduct-page-wrapper").scrollHeight,
            document.getElementById("porduct-page-wrapper").offsetHeight,
            document.getElementById("porduct-page-wrapper").clientHeight
        );
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    if($('.mdl-layout__content').scrollTop() + $('.mdl-layout__content').height() == getDocHeight()) {
           alert("bottom!");
    }
}, true);
```

Problem is, every time I change the page, and comes back, the number of times the event should called is multiplying. Probably it is binding event again and again, whenever I change the page or clicks link.
I am using Angular.js, how can I prevent this?

Comment: `mdl-layout__content` has the scroll or you want it on window scroll?

Comment: I want it on one of the class which is inside the content. I am genereating views in mdl-layout__content, using angular js.

Comment: what is meant was is your document scrollable or specific div is scrollable?

Comment: Specific div, Check question, I have added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can fix your issue with the exactly detecting of the body position in the current scroll event callback. Use the [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method of an `html element`:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
  var bodyRect = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getBoundingClientRect(); 
  if (bodyRect.bottom - window.innerHeight <= 20){
    // less then 20px rest to get the bottom
    alert("Bottom!");
  }
});
```

Comment: I have added more details